# Extract all data of a month from different years

Tags: python, time-series, dataset, pandas

Ok I had a typo in this question before which I have now corrected: my database (df_e) looks like this:

```
0,Country,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,Date,H2,Year,month,dates,a_diffH,H2a
1,IN,28.58,77.2,212,1964-09-15,-57.6,1964,9,1964-09-15,-3.18,-54.42
2,IN,28.58,77.2,212,1963-09-15,-120.0,1963,9,1963-09-15,-3.18,-116.82
3,IN,28.58,77.2,212,1964-05-15,28.2,1964,5,1964-05-15,-3.18,31.38
...
```

and I would like to save the data from the 9th month from the years 1963 and 1964 into a new df. For this I use the command:

```
df.loc[df_e['H2a'].isin(['1963-09-15', '1964-09-15'])]
```

But the result is

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Country, Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Date, H2, Year, month, dates, a_diffH, H2a]
Index: []
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Not sure if it is a typing error, but you are using the `df` dataframe to check for the dates and are using that to subset the `dfn` dataframe. Based on the error (index of the series and the indexed object do not match) this seems to cause the error since the indices are not aligned.

Comment: Oh, snap, yes, you're right. I have changed it now, but now I get the error message: `Empty DataFrame` but this shouldn´t be

Comment: I corrected my qustion

Comment: You are checking if the `H2a` column is any of the two dates, but in the data you are showing that column does not contain any dates.